# Array of working hours from 9:00 to 18:00

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I need to save reports of working hours to the database. The working hours are from 9:00 to 18:00

- I have the start date: 2018/06/01 13:00:00
- And the end date: 2018/06/04 17:00:00

The result should be an array of reports for each working day of working hours:

1. June 1: Checkin - **13:00**; Checkout **18:00**;

   --two weekend days are skipped--
2. June 4: Checkin - **09:00**; Checkout **18:00**;
3. June 5: Checkin **09:00**; Checkout **18:00**;
4. June 6: Checkin **9:00**; Checkout **17:00**;

Any idea how to do that?

Edit: Don't get me wrong, I don't expect anyone to write code for me :) I just need a hint to understand how to make the loop know when to start and when to end on each day. Should that be a loop for each hour of the working days provided?

Comment: Sounds like you have an idea, so go for it. We're not going to write the code for you, but if you get stuck with an error or other issue, post your code and we can help you out.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to start from, how the loop should should work. I need at least a start, or a small explanation of the logic behind it.

Comment: @PerSeM that really isn't how stackoverflow works, it's not a school or forum where you discuss a problem and work through it, it's a Q&A site for specific programming problems.

Comment: Well, if you want somehting to start : 1/ Start by making a function that will give you all working hours according to an hour begin and an hour end (you have some function to add 1h to a date for example, so just add 1h to the begin while < end for example)); 2/ Loop through your start_date / end_date and use your function to get what you want; 3/ Do whatever you want with this

Comment: @MickaelLeger basically you mean that I should loop through each hour, one by one, and if the total hour is more than 18:00 I should jump to another day?

I believe there should be a more efficient formula. But if I can't find anything than I will use your suggestion.

Comment: @PerSeM I read again what you want and I think my comment was wrong, sorry. I thought you wanted all hour by day (like 13-14h, 14-15h, 15-16h, etc.). We don't know how your database works or how you get your data, but you should try create a table with id | date | hour_begin | hour_end | (user_id maybe if you need by user / worker) and insert a new row by date...it's not clear what you want exactly and we have no information about how you get your data, what you already have, how you will use it, what you already did, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. I will paste it here in case someone finds any inspiration from it.

```
    function get_working_days($start_time = "", $end_time = "") {

        //getting the difference between $start_time and $end_time in days
        $diff = ceil(($end_time - $start_time) / 60 / 60 / 24);

        // fixing the difference if the request is for 1 day only
        if (($end_time - $start_time) > 32400 && ($end_time - $start_time) < 86400) {
            $diff += 1;
        }

        // 9:00 of the current day
        $day_start = strtotime("midnight", $start_time) + 32400;

        // 18:00 of the current day
        $day_end = strtotime("midnight", $end_time) + 64800;

        // setting the current day
        $curr_day = $day_start;

        // initiating the array
        $return = [];

        // looping through each day using the $diff variable
        for ($i=0; $i < $diff; $i++) {

            // adding reports while skipping weekends
            if (!is_weekend($curr_day)) {
                if ($i == 0 && $diff <= 1) { 
                    // first and only iteration
                    $return[] = array("checkin" => $start_time, "checkout" => $end_time);
                }elseif ($i == 0 && $i < ($diff - 1)) { 
                    // first but not only iteration
                    $return[] = array("checkin" => $start_time, "checkout" => $curr_day + 32400);
                }elseif ($i < ($diff - 1)) { 
                    // middle 
                    $return[] = array("checkin" => $curr_day, "checkout" => $curr_day + 32400);
                }else{ 
                    // end
                    $return[] = array("checkin" => $curr_day, "checkout" => $end_time);
                }
            }
            // going to the next day
            $curr_day += 86400;
        }

        return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to loop through each day using some php function like date(), or Datetime() class. Then ( in the loop ) you need add the day to the array with the respective working hours, but always check if the day is a weekend or not ( you can achieve this using the function or class stated above ). After the loop, you insert your array into your database.

Comment: How do I know the "respective hours"? This was my actual question. I can do a loop for each day, it's easy to count how many days are there, but how do I know how many hours should I put for each day, and when is the start time for first report and last report, and how the code would behave if the report would be just for a couple of hours for 1 day only?